# What is the highest repetition rate achieved for pulsed Terawatt and Petawatt-order lasers?

Tags: lasers

What is the highest repetition rate achieved for pulsed Terawatt and Petawatt-order lasers?

Answer (score 2):

In Europe, the SYLOS3 laser system  boasts one of the highest repetition rates 1kHz for high intensity lasers 15[TW] (December 2020) (see [Optics](https://optics.org/news/11/12/20#:%7E:text=The%20Szeged%20facility%20stands%20out,1%20kHz%20pulse%20repetition%20rate.%E2%80%9D).)

SYLOS is a part of the ELI-ALPS  European Facility in Szeged Hungary, which has operates/plans for four main laser beamlines, operating at different regimes of repetition rates and peak powers:

- Single Cycle (SYLOS): 1 kHz, >35 mJ, <6.6 fs (100 mJ version in progress)   **(~10-20[TW])**
- High Field (HF): 10 Hz, 34 J, <17 fs  **(~ 2[PW])**
- High Repetition Rate (HR): 100 kHz, >5 mJ, <6 fs  **(~ 1 [TW] slightly less)**
- MID-Infrared (MIR): 100 kHz, >140 μJ, 4 optical cycle pulses at 3.2 μm

[Shameless plug: I've been involved in a very small degree with its development](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6455/aa6ee8/meta)